# hide div based on setAtrribute

Tags: jquery, html, session-variables, hidden, setattribute

I have this code which is contains a session.setattribute notification,

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
     <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
     <div style="text-align: center;">${notification}</div>
</div>
```

I want the div to be hidden and only be shown if ${notification} has a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution:http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/h1vknorg/

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
     <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
     <div id="notification" style="text-align: center;">${notification}</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
 if($('#notification').html().length < 1) {
     $('#notification').hide(); 
    }
```